# Custom format for chapter number, chapter title and chapter name

Tags: titlesec

I am using the `titlesec` package for formatting the chapter style (book class).

I follow this thread:
[How to add a line between chapter number and chapter title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52470/how-to-add-a-line-between-chapter-number-and-chapter-title)
and get (almost) desired results.

[image]

The format I need is:

- Normal font for the word "Chapter" and bold font for the chapter
  number (already got).
- However I also need the bold font for the
  chapter name

My titlesec format:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\LARGE}
  {\chaptertitlename~\bfseries\HUGE\thechapter}{1pc}
  {{\color{black}\titlerule[1pt]}\vspace{1pt}\MakeUppercase}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries\LARGE}{}{1pc}
  {\MakeUppercase}
```

May I ask how to get the desired result?

Also May I ask if there is a way to set precise font size (like 20pt, 24pt) for each element in the chapter title instead of using `\large` `\huge`?

Comment: `normalfont` and `LARGE` for `Chapter` -- `bfseries` and `LARGE` for `chapter number` -- is this the requirement -- just change the appropriate line of code --`{\normalfont\LARGE\chaptertitlename~\bfseries\LARGE\thechapter}{1pc}`

Comment: for the chapter title in bold modify the code -- `{{\color{brown}\titlerule[2pt]}\vspace{1pc}\MakeUppercase}` as `{{\color{brown}\titlerule[2pt]}\vspace{1pc}\bfseries\MakeUppercase}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec, lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor} 

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{}
{\normalfont\LARGE\chaptertitlename~\bfseries\LARGE\thechapter}{1pc}
{{\color{brown}\titlerule[2pt]}\vspace{1pc}\MakeUppercase}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
{\normalfont\bfseries\LARGE}{}{1pc}
{\MakeUppercase}

\begin{document}

    
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

**AND for the chapter title in bold**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec, lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor} 

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{}
{\normalfont\LARGE\chaptertitlename~\bfseries\LARGE\thechapter}{1pc}
{{\color{brown}\titlerule[2pt]}\vspace{1pc}\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
{}{}{1pc}
{}

\begin{document}

    
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]